# Angular 9 Ionic 5 httpclient post sending empty array

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular9, angular-httpclient, ionic5

I am creating an app with Angular 9 and Ionic 5 and I am very new at this so forgive me if I missed something obvious.  The following is my App code:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
etc...

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  authenticate(phone: string, password: string) {
    let frmData = new URLSearchParams();
    // let frmData = new FormData(); //just to show that I have tried this also
    const headeroptions = {
      // 'enctype': 'multipart/form-frmData;', // when using FormData above
      'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
    };
    frmData.append('emailOrMobile', phone);
    frmData.append('password', password);
    console.log("login: " + phone + " " + password); //this shows the values correctly
    console.log("frmData: " + frmData); //frmData: emailOrMobile=1234567890&password=111111
    return this.http.post<any>('https://example.com/APP/login.php', {frmData}, {headers: headeroptions}
      // {"emailOrMobile":phone, "password":password} //Also tried without creating the object beforehand
    ).subscribe(data => {
      console.log("Subscribed Data: ");
      console.log(data);
    },
      error => {
            console.log('error: ' + error.error);
            console.log('Name: ' + error.name);
            console.log('Message: ' + error.message);
            console.log('Status: ' + error.status);
          });
  }
```

I have also tried other versions where I have replaced .subscribe... etc. with:

```
.pipe(tap(this.setUserData.bind(this)));
```

but that hasn't worked either.  There are a lot of solutions out there, but most deal with older versions of Angular and do not use HttpClient or they do and suggest subscribing to the observable - which I am already doing.

At the other end, the php code is straightforward:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
```

If I echo or try to use $data, it is an empty array that prints as {} or just a blank space (can't get it consistently to print '{}').  I even tried

```
count($data);
```

and that returns 0.

Comment: Have you tried passing the arg to the http.post() as `frmData` instead of`{frmData}`?

Comment: Thanx, just tried that - didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a test here in my local machine and it worked passing the args as a javascript object:

`{ emailOrMobile: phone, password: password}`

In the php script in the backend I usually allow CORS requests. I am not sure if you do need in your environment (see the command `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`).

The full typescript of the page:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab1',
  templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss']
})
export class Tab1Page {
    
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.authenticate('123', 'mypassword');
  }

  authenticate(phone: string, password: string) {
    const headeroptions = {
      'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
    };
  
    let params =  { emailOrMobile: phone, password: password};
    return this.http.post<any>('http://localhost/backend/authtest.php', params, {headers: headeroptions}).subscribe(data => {
      console.log("Subscribed Data: ");
      console.log(data);
    },
    error => {
      console.log('error: ' + error.error);
      console.log('Name: ' + error.name);
      console.log('Message: ' + error.message);
      console.log('Status: ' + error.status);
    }); 
  }
}
```

The php script in the backend `authtest.php`:

```php
<?php
    //Allow requests from different domain:
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
    
    echo json_encode([ 'success' => true, 'params' => $data]);
```

The output I got in Chrome after runing the ionic application:

[image]

Comment: Already tried that, see the line: "// {"emailOrMobile":phone, "password":password} //Also tried without creating the object beforehand"
(sorry, I mistyped phone instead of emailOrMobile in my original post)

Comment: I have tested that code here and that code worked for me. I will edit my answer to include the php code I have used in the backend as well

Comment: instead of `count($data)`, what is the output of `print_r($data);` in the php script?

Comment: just edited my answer including the full files and the chrome printscreen, maybe it helps you track the error in your env.

Comment: I save the value of $data and count($data) in a MySQL database - since I can't really see the output from the api.

Meanwhile, I used your php code (the last line - everyting else I already had) and I get: params: {…}
​​
frmdata: []
​​​
length: 0
​​​
<prototype>: Array []

Comment: That it means you are still passing the params as `{ frmdata}` which wont work. Try again passing the params as `{ emailOrMobile: phone, password: password};` and tell me what is the output.

Comment: Thanx @francisco, some progress!  Yes, I am getting the data back as it was sent.  (params: {…}
​​
password: "123456"
​​
phone: "9370131365"
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
success: true). However, it is still inserting just a string ( the word "Array") when I insert the $data into the database.

Comment: Success! $a = $data["emailOrMobile"]; and $b = $data["password"]; both give values.  I think I can figure out the rest.  Thanx Francisco!